# Is the classname() equivalent to a class object?

Tags: c++, transform, function-object

I know this might be a stupid question but I am not sure how to describe it properly. 
When I try to call `std::transform` function for example,

```
template < class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperator >
  OutputIterator transform ( InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1,
                             OutputIterator result, UnaryOperator op )
```

one may write `UnaryOperator op;` and then call `transform(..,..,.., op);`

However I also see people write just `transform(..,..,..,UnaryOperator());`

My question is: is it true that `classname()` is equivalent to a class object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exactly do you mean by `classname()`, but when you write like this:

```
UnaryOperator op;
transform(..,..,.., op);
```

... you create `op` object of class `UnaryOperator` and pass it to `transform`. Its lifetime depends on the scope where it was defined. I.e. you can access it after the call to `transform`.

And when you write like this:

```
transform(..,..,.., UnaryOperator());
```

... you essentially create a temporary object of class `UnaryOperator` and pass it to `transform` function, and its lifetime is tied to expression. Also, in this case it will be either a constant reference or an "rvalue". Whereas in the first case it is either non-constant or constant reference.

Comment: thanks, so what you mean is that when you write UnaryOperator() you are calling the default constructor.

Comment: The *expression* `UnaryOperator()` is always an rvalue. The same text can however be parsed as a declaration, depending on the context.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You are right, what's the right name for the case where a function awaits an rvalue reference like `&&` (C++11)?

Comment: @ephemerality: Yes, in that context. It could also mean a declaration as Cheersandhth have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

For a given type `T`, in the right circumstance, the expression `T()` evaluates to a temporary, default-constructed object of type `T`. Here are some cases where this can be used:

```
// Ex 1:
T x; x = T();   // overwrite `x` with a copy of a default-T

// Ex 2:
T x = T();      // copy-initialize from default-T (probably elided)

// Ex 3 (note that temporaries bind to const&):
void foo(int n = 10, T const & t = T());  // default argument

// Ex 4:
std::string format_me(int a)
{
    return static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << a).str();
    //                            temporary ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Beware of situations where `T()` means something else:

```
{
    T t(T());   // `t` is _not_ an object of type T!
}
```